# How to hide text in QML TextInput if it is out of bounds

Tags: qt, qml

[image: Screenshot]

I try to hide the text if it width more then Rectangle id: field. But it does not work "from the box". How can I hide text if the width of text bigger then Rectangle's (where TextInput location) width?

```
    Rectangle {
        id: field
        border.color: "green"
        border.width: 2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width:  root.width / 2
        height: 30

        TextInput {
            id: textEdit1

            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.right: okButton.left
            width: field.width - okButton.width
            height: field.height
            text: "Entered"
            padding: 3
            verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignLeft
        }

        Button {
            id: okButton

            width: field.width * 0.15
            height: parent.height
            anchors.right: field.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: field.verticalCenter
            text: "Ok"
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the [`clip`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop) property of the Rectangle:

```
Rectangle {
    id: field
    clip: true
    // ...
```

[image]

Comment: How to add `elide` into `TextInput` ?